# Navigation: Setting page Anchor tag (javascript or css)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Newbie here trying to build a template for spring class quarter which begins next week. Everything is working as hoped except that when i click the chevron (the little downward pointing arrow) the page does not slide to the element as hoped. If I set the id of the first assignment to 'profile' it will work, other wise if i leave it as 'a01' for assignment 01' it does not work and i have to manually scroll down to the first assignment which is not a great user experience.

I want to find how this is happening as the way i implemented it i missed something as it doesn't scroll down as hoped when i click on the arrow. I think that it's related to javascript files being used which i know little about, but I want to. Once i understand it, i believe that i can create a nice short tag and call the kind of anchor i want with php, but right now i'd like to just get it to scroll down to the a01 div.

See: http://kirby.max-o-matic.com

See: http://www.kirby.max-o-matic.com/itc216/

I believe that i have an error set in javascript somewhere as the anchor tag is created in the javascript (i think).

I've tried to be as specific as i can but i am a new and pushing my boundaries of what i understand in making this site for my upcoming class assignments.

thank you for any help or guidance given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [kirby.max-o-matic.com/itc216/](http://kirby.max-o-matic.com/itc216/) change:

```
<a href="#profile" class="scroll-down">
```

to:

```
<a href="#a010" class="scroll-down">
```

Comment: I will go check this, and likely, say 'damn my dyslexia'

Comment: revised the link to read: '<div id="#a010" class="container">' but it still seems to be to profile. I've checked my pathing, etc. Still not working. Weird yes?

Comment: Thank you got it working! Your noting the 'class="scroll-down"> let me find the right place as i've chopped my pages up into lots of includes.

Answer (score 1):

Your div has an id of a010, so thats what you need to put into your anchor tag. I do not see it actually working when I load the itc216 page with #profile.

```
<a href="#a010">a010</a>
```